# Editing .aspx file makes Visual Studio unresponsive

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 on Windows 7.  When I'm editing .aspx file VS stalls and thinks for about 3 sec every time I add a tag. Very frustrating. I'm guessing its doing some kind of compilation or checking.  What can I do to make VS more responsive?

Answer (score 3):

you'll want to turn of HTML validation

[image]
<sub>(source: [episerver.com](http://labs.episerver.com/Global/xmlrpc/111856/2008/06/24/image_thumb.png))</sub>

http://labs.episerver.com/en/Blogs/Steve-Celius/Dates/112266/6/Speed-up-Visual-Studio/

Comment: The linked article has a very options for speeding up performance, have you tried them?

Comment: tried every one of those. it looks like it helped a little but for the most part, VS still freezes at random intervals.